# 24 bit adc data compression using something similar to huffman coding

Tags: compression, huffman-code

I am trying to compress a 24 bit value. But I do not have any prior experience in compression. So, I was wondering if someone can give me some insight or suggestion on how to encode and decode the 24 bit value using verilog or matlab.

Problem: I am dividing the 24 bit value into 6 chunks of 4 bits. each 4 bit has a unique path in a huffman tree. I follow that tree to find the compressed value, but I am stumbling on how to decode the values. The decoder will be aware of the tree since it's static. But when the decoder gets a stream of bits, how would it know how to decode it.

Attached is a picture to clarify what I am saying.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SomsK.png)

Comment: Please post your code, including (1) a sample input, (2) the output you're currently getting, and (3) the output you expect or want to get.

Comment: Hi daniel,

I don't have a code for it. The picture gives an example of my input sample and the compressed value of the input. I don't know how to uncompress it after i compress the value

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram is not a Huffman code, or any code for that matter. Symbols are at the leaves of the tree, never in the middle. The way your diagram is structured, there is no way to distinguish, for example, 0, 00, 000, or 0000 from each other. A Huffman code, which is a prefix code, when correctly constructed, can never reuse a prefix in a different code.

Comment: That is why God invented Google.